# Update Highcarts series data form axios request in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, axios

I'm trying to update the series data in my `Highchart`. I'm using the `highcharts-vue` component.

Within my template I have:

```
<highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
```

In the `data` of my `Vue` component I have:

```
data () {
    return {
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                height: 300,
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Amount of visitors per day'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Visitors',
                data: [],
                color: '#44B8D6'
            }]
        }
    }
},
```

And my `Axios` request:

```
const vm = this;
const request = 'get_visitors';
this.$http({
    method:'get',
    url:'/api',
    params: {
        request: request
    },
    responseType:'json'
})
.then(function(response) {
    let setData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        setData.push(response.data[i].data)
    }
    setData = setData.map(Number);
    console.log(setData);
    vm.chartOptions.series.data = setData
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

But the chart doesn't get updated. The `console.log(setData)` actually shows me the array, so the request goes OK.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you could use `this` inside your promise directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in this line:

```
vm.chartOptions.series.data = setData
```

Since `series` is an array, you need to specify in which `series` you new data, like so:

```
vm.chartOptions.series[0].data = setData
```

You can find an example here: https://jsbin.com/heyayogudo/edit?html,js,output